# Need to prohibit negative index values in array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array `date_array`.  If `i` is `0`, I'd like `date_array[i-1]` to return `nil` or an exception.  I thought I could derive a subclass of Array for this, but I'm not sure where to go after that.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this, but you shouldn't need to. You're going about this the wrong way, I feel, since the responsibility is yours, not Array's, to check the index value being passed.

**Merely an example**

```
def get_array_value (i)
  return data_array[i - 1] unless i < 0
  return nil
end
```

However, if you insist, this solution may work for you.

```
# arr = SpecialArray.new([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

class SpecialArray < Array

  def [](i)
    return super(i) unless i < 0
    return nil
  end  

end
```

Comment: yep, changing the direct call to the array via [] to a function (like yours above) works just as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I agree with Adam, it'd be ideal to control the indexes instead of doing this:

```
class Ary < Array
    def [](i)
        return nil if i < 0
        super
    end
end

a = Ary.new([1, 2, 3])
b = Array.new([1, 2, 3])

#try access with -1 (normally would show last)
p a[-1] #=> nil
p b[-1] #=> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be doing things incorrectly. That being said:

You could use a hash instead of an array. Hashes won't re-interpret `hash[-1]` to mean something else.